# regular expressions with grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have this command right here:

```
grep -B10 -A10 '14:14:50 {"channels":["/alerts/6979/new"],"data":"New alerts for unit 6979"}' mygateway.log
```

Rather than searching for 14:14:50 I would like the 50 to be replaced with any number. So I was thinking to use the "." to represent any character in a regular expression. However, in programming languages you usually signify a regex with something like \abc.xyz\ where "." could be any character and any number of characters. But when I use "." in that grep string above it doesn't give me anything back.

Comment: why not `[0-9][0-9]`? Or `[0-9]\?` instead of `50`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `.` is used to signify any *single* character. So the `.` would match the `5` in `50` but, with nothing to match the `0`, the rest of the line fails to match. In any case, since you know that what you're looking for is any *number*, you should be more specific with your regex. Match any number with:

```
[0-9]\+
```

If you know that this number can have an optional fractional part (after a decimal point), you can use the following:

```
[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)?
```

The backslash before the `+` and the parens should be omitted if you're using `grep`'s `-P` (PCRE) option.

If you do plan to use the `-P` option, you should know it's not in the POSIX standard and may not be available on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `-P` flag to enable Perl compatible regular expressions and use `\d`:

```
grep -P -B10 -A10 '14:14:\d+ {"channels":["/alerts/6979/new"],"data":"New alerts for unit 6979"}' mygateway.log
```

You could also really simplify it by making it less restrictive (the details depend on your input data of course but this should work):

```
grep -P -B10 -A10 '14:14:\d+.*channels.*alerts/6979/new.*data.*New' mygateway.log
```

I am assuming that if the line matches both `/alerts/6979/new/` and `New`, the rest is unchanging.

Comment: Perl's `\d` class is notorious for behaving unexpectedly in non-ASCII environments. `[0-9]` is usually what is meant. I'm sure you know this already; this is an FYI for other readers.

Comment: Read [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) under the heading "Digits".

Comment: @JosephR. That might apply to `perl`, but probably not to the PCREs (which are _not_ perl regular expressions) as used in GNU `grep -P`. Even `echo '\u09EA' | LC_ALL=bn_BD.UTF-8 grep -P '(*UCP)\d'` doesn't seem to match, though that may be down to GNU libc or to my actual bengali locale definition

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the clarification and the interesting example. Can you please explain the `(*UCP)` part, though?

Comment: @JosephR. I did _not_ know that, thanks! It's never been an issue for me given that all the locales I've ever used serve Arabic numerals but that's good to know.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - your example appeared to work for me. I'm assuming that I should get a match from grep, right?

Comment: @slm, see the [PCRE manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt), that't to use unicode properties for `\d`, which if we're to believe Joseph's link to the perl documentation, should make `\d` match the unicode character U09EA (a Bengali decimal digit), but in my case doesn't (you need a shell/echo that supports the `\uxxxx` notation like zsh).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the link. It says that character classes like `\d`, `\w`, `\s`,... support only ASCII characters by default but can be made to support Unicode ones if `PCRE_UCP` is set.

Comment: @JosephR. Yes, and as I said, you can turn PCRE_UCP by adding `(*UCP)` in the regexp, but even then I don't see it matching non-ASCII digits on my system.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - OK so the use of `(*UCP)` on my system did work, I'm `en_US.utf8`.

Comment: @slm, by _did work_, do you mean it displayed that [৪ (Bengali digit four) character](http://www.charbase.com/09ea-unicode-bengali-digit-four), or as I suspect you're seeing `\u09EA` (including the two ascii digits 0 and 9) because you're using an implementation of `echo` that doesn't understand the `\uxxxx` notation?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - yeah that's why I was asking, I see the `\u09EA`. So that means it didn't work, right?

Comment: @slm. yes, if your `echo` doesn't support the `\u09EA` notation, either run the same command from `zsh` or use `printf '\340\247\252\n'` instead to hard code the UTF-8 sequence. Or I believe recent versions of `ksh93`, GNU and `bash` `printf` support `printf '\u09EA\n'`. ksh93 and bash seem to support `echo $'\u09EA'` as well.

Comment: My Fedora14 Bash (4.1.7(1)) can't do any of the methods, my Ubuntu 12.10 Bash (4.2.37(1)) can do the `printf` and `echo $'..'`.

Comment: @slm what about `echo -e '\u09EA'`?

Comment: @terdon - works with Ubuntu's Bash, not with Fedora's Bash.